# Variable Data Not Being Added to TKinter SQLite3 Database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am developing an application that allows a user to answer music, sight-reading based questions. I am attempting to add their scores to an SQLite database. All of the code is currently working, and I am not receiving any error messages regarding my database. My issue is  that the variables, timestamp, LevelDatabase, CorrectDatabase and Incorrect database are not being written to the database.
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
from tkinter import font
import time
import random
import datetime
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Results.db') # DATABASE
c = conn.cursor() # DATABASE
#Main Menu


helv12= font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=40, weight=font.BOLD)
helv13=font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight=font.BOLD)
root.configure(background="pink1")
root.title("MySight: Main Menu")
root.geometry("1368x766")
#root.iconbitmap('Final.ico')
photo=tk.PhotoImage(file="FinalFinalLogo.gif")
w=tk.Label(root, image=photo)
w.pack()


#Level1
class Levels:
        def __init__(self,master):
                frame = tk.Frame(master)
                frame.pack()
                self.Levels=tk.Button(frame, text="Levels", fg="white" ,bg="pink1", font=helv12, height=1, width=8, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, command=self.NewWindow)
                self.Levels.pack()
                global QuestionCounter
                QuestionCounter=0
                global Correct
                Correct = 0
                global Incorrect
                Incorrect = 0


        # DEFINES WHAT THE NEW WINDOW SHOULD LOOK LIKE
        def NewWindow(self):

                Window =tk.Toplevel(root)
                Window.geometry("800x1000")
                Window.configure(background="pink1")
                Window.title("Level 1")
                c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ResultsStorage(timestamp TEXT, LevelDatabase TEXT, CorrectDatabase REAL, IncorrectDatabase REAL)') # DATABASE



                # LIST OF QUESTIONS
                Question1=("Question1")
                Question2=("Question2")
                Question3=("Question3")
                Question4=("Question4")
                Question5=("Question5")
                Question6=("Question6")
                Question7=("Question7")
                Question8=("Question8")
                Question9=("Question9")
                Question10=("Question10")
                # LIST OF ANSWERS
                Answer1=("A")
                Answer2=("B")
                Answer3=("C")
                Answer4=("D")
                Answer5=("E")
                Answer6=("F")
                Answer7=("G")
                Answer8=("C#")
                Answer9=("A#")
                Answer10=("B#")
                # DEFINITIONS OF VARIABLES
                Questions = [Question1,Question2,Question3,Question4,Question5,Question6,Question7,Question8,Question9, Question10]
                Answers = [Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, Answer5, Answer6, Answer7, Answer8, Answer9, Answer10]
                RandomQuestion=(random.choice(Questions))
                LevelDatabase = ("1")





                # DEFINES LAYOUT OF NEW WINDOW
                Name = tk.Label(Window, text = "Level 1", fg="white", bg="pink1", font=helv13, height=1, width=20, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
                Name.pack()
                label = tk.Label(Window, text=RandomQuestion, fg="white", bg="pink1", font=helv13, height=1, width=20, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
                label.pack()
                Label2 = tk.Label(Window,fg="white", bg="pink1", font=helv13, height=1, width=70, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
                Label2.pack()
                entry = tk.Entry(Window, width=70)
                entry.configure(background="pink1")
                entry.pack()




               # DEFINES FIRST LEVEL
                def Level1():
                        global QuestionCounter

                        UserInput = entry.get()# RANDOMLY PRINTS QUESTION


                        QuestionCounter= QuestionCounter+ 1
                        print ("You are on Question",QuestionCounter,)
                        if str(UserInput) in str(Answers) and len(UserInput): # AND IF THE ANSWER OR CAPITAL ANSWER IS THE SAME AS THE CORRECT ANSWER
                                global Correct                                               
                                Correct = Correct+ 1 # ADD ONE TO QUESTION COUNTER
                                print ("Correct")
                                entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                                label.config(text = RandomQuestion)



                        elif str(UserInput) not in str(Answers) and len (UserInput):
                                global Incorrect                                            
                                Incorrect = Incorrect+1
                                print ("Wrong")
                                print (QuestionCounter)
                                entry.delete(0,tk.END)

                        if QuestionCounter == 9:
                                        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                                        label.config(text = "Correct: "+str(Correct) + " Incorrect:   "+str(Incorrect))

                                        if Correct>7:

                                                GoodJob=("You did a good job on Level 1.")
                                                Label2.config (text = str(GoodJob))
                                                file=open ("Results.txt","w")
                                                file.write (str(GoodJob))
                                                file.write("\n")
                                                file.write("You got"+str(Correct)+"correct")
                                                file.write("\n")
                                                file.write("You got"+str(Incorrect)+"incorrect")

                                        if Correct < 5:

                                                BadJob=("You did a bad job on Level 1")
                                                Label2.config (text = str(BadJob))
                                                file=open ("Results.txt","w")
                                                file.write(str(BadJob))
                                                file.write("\n")
                                                file.write("You got"+str(Correct)+"correct")
                                                file.write("\n")
                                                file.write("You got"+str(Incorrect)+"incorrect")


                def dynamic_data_entry(self):
                        global dynamic_data_entry
                        #this is what adds the data to the database. 
                        timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
                        LevelDatabase = Window.Level
                        CorrectDatabase = Window.Correct
                        IncorrectDatabase = Window.Incorrect
                        c.execute("INSERT INTO ResultsStorage (timestamp, LevelDatabase, CorrectDatabase, IncorrectDatabase) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(timestamp, LevelDatabase, CorrectDatabase, IncorrectDatabase))
                        conn.commit()
                        self.writetodatabase()

                def writetodatabase(self):
                        for i in range(1):
                                time.sleep(1)
                        c.close()
                        conn.close()




                #NextLevel = tk.Button (Window, text = "Next Level", command= Level2, fg="white", bg="pink1",font=helv13, height=1, width=20, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)


                NextQuestion = tk.Button(Window,text = "Next Question",command = Level1, fg="white", bg="pink1", font=helv13, height=1, width=20, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
                NextQuestion.pack()











class Results():
        def __init__(self,master):
                frame = tk.Frame(master)
                frame.pack()
                self.Levels=tk.Button(frame, text="Results", fg="white" ,bg="pink1", font=helv12, height=1, width=8, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, command=self.NewWindow)
                self.Levels.pack()
        def NewWindow(self):

                Window =tk.Toplevel(root)
                Window.geometry("1500x1500")
                Window.configure(background="pink1")
                self.connection = sqlite3.connect('Results.db')
                self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
                self.dateLabel = tk.Label(Window, text="Date", width=10, fg="white" ,bg="pink1", font=helv12, height=1,highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0,)
                self.dateLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
                self.LevelLabel = tk.Label(Window, text = "Level", width=10,fg="white" ,bg="pink1", font=helv12, height=1, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0,)
                self.LevelLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
                self.CorrectLabel = tk.Label(Window, text="Correct", width=10,fg="white" ,bg="pink1", font=helv12, height=1, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0,)
                self.CorrectLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)
                self.IncorrectLabel = tk.Label(Window, text="Incorrect", width=10,fg="white" ,bg="pink1", font=helv12, height=1, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0,)
                self.IncorrectLabel.grid(row=0, column=3)
                self.showallrecords()
        def showallrecords(self):
                data = self.readfromdatabase()
                for index, dat in enumerate(data):
                    Label(self.master, text=dat[0]).grid(row=index+1, column=0)
                    Label(self.master, text=dat[1]).grid(row=index+1, column=1)
                    Label(self.master, text=dat[2]).grid(row=index+1, column=2)
                    Label(self.master, text=dat[3]).grid(row=index+1, column=3)

        def readfromdatabase(self):
                self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ResultsStorage")
                return self.cur.fetchall()





Quit = tk.Button(root, text="Exit",fg="white" ,bg="pink1", font=helv12, height=1, width=40, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, command=root.destroy)


#pack (add) the widget into the window
Levels(root)
#Practice(root)
Results(root)
Quit.pack()
root.mainloop #Run the thing
```

Comment: It appears you have a function named `dynamic_data_entry` that saves data to the database, but there is no code that calls that function.

Comment: `dynamic_data_entry` is called within the class `Levels` though, wouldn't that mean it is called when `Levels` is run? @BryanOakley

Comment: When I search the code for "dynamic_data_entry", it only shows up twice. Once as the name of a function, and once as the name of a global variable. Where do you think it's being called? On what line of the code that you posted is it called?

Comment: I'm very new to both Python and SQLite so please bear with me. I thought that `dynamic_data_entry` is called automatically when I run levels as that is where it's defined. Where should I call it then? @BryanOakley

Comment: functions are not automatically called. I don't know where you should call it from, this is your code. I guess you call it when the user clicks a button.

Comment: I tried to turn it into a class and then call it at the bottom where all other classes are called. Now the entire code is broken and I'm lost as to what to do.